# How to download images from websites using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to save images from websites, is it possible using beautiful soup library in Python. Do we need the pillow library? or can we convert them into numpy arrays and process tem using open CV?

Comment: I found this useful. https://www.shellvoide.com/python/scraping-and-download-all-images-from-a-web-page-python/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without providing any specifics, all anyone can do is give a general answer. But yes it is possible.

I'd imagine you would use beautifulsoup to pull the url of an image, then use that url to pull and save the image. So Something like:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
import bs4

url = 'some.site.com'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

image = soup.find('img')
image_url = image['src']


img = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream = True).raw)

img.save('image.jpg')
```